# Facing Two many rows error on insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Its very simple question.

```
INSERT INTO crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA(NAME,OLD_ID) 
VALUES (
(   SELECT s.NAME FROM crm.dbo.SURROGATE as s
    INNER JOIN crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA ON (s.ID != crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID)
    WHERE crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID IS NULL
),
(   SELECT SURROGATE.ID FROM crm.dbo.SURROGATE 
    LEFT JOIN crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA ON (crm.dbo.SURROGATE.ID = crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID) 
    WHERE crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID IS NULL
)
)
```

When i execute the above query below  error occurs

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I can understand the error, subquery returns more than one rows, on the other hand it inserting one by one row.

what is its solution? By applying inner join  Instead of left join its doesn't through an error. so question is that why its solution is inner join. why not any thing else. I do not want to apply inner join on it. and sorry for massive content. But thanks  in advance

Comment: Do left join instead of the subquery. Or make sure the subquery returns only one row.

Comment: First of all, don't use `VALUES`if you want to insert results of a select. Instead define one query which returns name and ID as reuired and then insert via `INSERT INTO crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA SELECT...`. Secondly, it would be helpful to see the table structure.

Comment: thanks jarlh its working first you suggest me that solution so please answer it. I will mark it as accepted answer. if you don't want then I will mark jayasurya answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Not use Values when you are using a select statement to insert. Make it a Join statement instead. Because when using values you can provide only 1 set at a time. Maybe Try This

```
INSERT INTO crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA(NAME,OLD_ID) 
SELECT SURROGATE.name,SURROGATE.ID FROM crm.dbo.SURROGATE  
    LEFT JOIN crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA ON (crm.dbo.SURROGATE.ID = crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID) 
    WHERE crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The error mean that you obatin more than a result for a single result value as the content of a column for an single insert command

but looking to you code you could sue a simple  insert select with a single select for both the columns results eg:

```
Insert Into crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA(NAME,OLD_ID) 
select s.NAME,  s.ID 
from  crm.dbo.SURROGATE as s
inner join crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA on s.ID!=crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID 
where crm.dbo.UPDATE_DATA.OLD_ID is null
```